# Word to Excel data transfer of bookmark section locations (cross references)

Tags: excel, vba, bookmarks, cross-reference

I am trying to obtain the numbered locations of my bookmarks (paragraph number without context) in a Word document (a lengthy legal document template) and. I am currently using the following code to pull the bookmarked text values from the Word document into an Excel workbook I've built out to grab other data from other sources, but I haven't been able to figure out how to manipulate the code to grab the bookmark's paragraph numbers (I searched high and low for this one too, and am a VBA newbie. I know just enough to be dangerous, but not enough to be helpful lol). Please Help!

```
Sub SectionLocationImportTESTING()
Dim intDocCount As Integer
Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, xlWb As Excel.Workbook, xlWs As Excel.Worksheet
Dim BookmarkText As String

Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If wdApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There are no MS Word Documents open.", vbInformation, "No Word Documents open"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set xlWb = ThisWorkbook
Set xlWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Input")
intDocCount = wdApp.Documents.Count

If intDocCount > 1 Then
    MsgBox "There are " & intDocCount & " Word Documents open." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Please close the additional MS Word Documents", vbCritical, "Too many Word Documents open!"
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

With wdApp
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
    wdDoc.Activate
    
'This is very abbreviated, I have about 300 bookmarks that transfer

If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Section_Rent") = True Then
    BookmarkText = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Section_Rent").Range.Text
xlWs.Cells(202, 22) = ("Section_Rent")
xlWs.Cells(202, 23) = BookmarkText
End If

End With

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Data_Input_Table").PivotFields("Trimmed Data"). _
    PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionIsGreaterThan, Value1:="0"
    

    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "Transfer is complete."

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking for the auto-numbered text of the bookmark's paragraph? E.g. (a), (1) etc. In your code that could be `wdDoc.Bookmarks("Section_Rent").Range.ListFormat.ListString`, and instead of hardcoding your bookmark name, you can consider looping through the bookmarks collection (but I hope you have a format for the bookmark that you can use to filter through as bookmark tends to be used for tons of other things as well)

Comment: I have no idea what auto-number is. I would like excel to be told by word what Section number the text I bookmark is in. Like a crossreferenced section number from word.

Comment: I also have no idea what looping is or how its done.

Comment: Based on your comment in Tim's answer, what you want should be `wdDoc.Bookmarks("Section_Rent").Range.ListFormat.ListString`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straight-forward way of doing that.
You could do this for example:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print ParagraphNumber(Selection.Range)
End Sub


Function ParagraphNumber(rng As Range)
    ParagraphNumber = rng.Document.Range(0, rng.End).Paragraphs.Count
End Function
```

...but it will also count "empty" paragraphs.

If you have a lot of bookmarks, you could consider listing the names in your Excel sheet and then looping over that range to run the text extraction.  If you hard-code all those names into your VBA that's going to be very hard to maintain.

E.g.

```vb
'...
Dim c As Range, bm As String, rngBM As Word.Range

'...
'...

Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
wdDoc.Activate
'range with your bookmark names
Set rngBM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bookmarks").Range("A2:A300")

For Each c In rngBM.Cells
    bm = c.Value 'bookmark name
    If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bm) Then
        Set rngBM = wdDoc.Bookmarks(bm).Range
        'for demo purposes just putting info next to the bookmark name...
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = rngBM.Text
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = ParagraphNumber(rngBM)
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: I have an excel formula that pairs the bookmarks I have into the overall formulas. I was hoping that there was some kind of way to integrate an "InsertCrossReference" or "GetCrossReference" that I see used in word. Example:

    Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark", ReferenceKind:= _
        wdNumberNoContext, ReferenceItem:="SECTION_RENT", InsertAsHyperlink:=True _
        , IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "

But either way, I have no idea how to plug in what you just listed... TOTAL beginner.

Comment: *** It won't let me edit, I have an excel worksheet that generates the bulk of the code for the bookmarks. it's 800+ lines so I didn't include it here

Comment: If you are using Excel to generate VBA then you can instead use that same information to drive the extraction (i.e. without generating 800+ lines of VBA). You only show one book mark though, so it's difficult to see what pattern is followed with the others. It might help your question to include a screenshot of a portion of the document (redacted as appropriate) indicating the location of an example bookmark and the "Paragraph number" you want to extract along with the bookmark text.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to get the paragraph number, depending on what you want:

**Option 1**

This will get the exact string of the auto-numbering that you see in the paragraph itself:

E.g. the below paragraph will get you `1.`

1. This is a test paragraph.

```
If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Section_Rent") Then
    Dim BookmarkText As String
    BookmarkText = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Section_Rent").Range.Text
                    
    xlWs.Cells(202, 22) = "Section_Rent"
    xlWs.Cells(202, 23) = BookmarkText
            
    Dim BookmarkParaNum As String
    BookmarkParaNum = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Section_Rent").Range.ListFormat.ListString
    
    xlWs.Cells(202, 24) = BookmarkParaNum
End If
```

**Option 2**
This will get the string that you see if you insert a cross reference to the paragraph:

Using the below code for the same paragraph in Option 1 will give you just `1`, the same as what inserting it as cross reference will get you.

```
wdDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraphAfter 'A temporary paragraph for inserting field later

Dim fieldRng As Range
Set fieldRng = wdDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Duplicate

If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Section_Rent") Then
    Dim BookmarkText As String
    BookmarkText = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Section_Rent").Range.Text
                            
    xlWs.Cells(202, 22) = "Section_Rent"
    xlWs.Cells(202, 23) = BookmarkText
                            
    fieldRng.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark", ReferenceKind:=wdNumberNoContext, ReferenceItem:="Section_Term", InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
    Dim tempField As Field
    Set tempField = fieldRng.Fields(1)
    
    Dim BookmarkParaNum As String
    BookmarkParaNum = tempField.Result
       
    xlWs.Cells(202, 24) = BookmarkParaNum
    
    tempField.Delete
End If

fieldRng.Delete 'Delete the temporary paragraph
```